# Method not writing to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

While I'm trayoung to create new object of class recipe, no data being inserted into direction model table.

Recipe controller:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_recipe, only:[:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    def index
        @recipe = Recipe.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @recipe = Recipe.new
    end

    def create
        @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)

        if @recipe.save
            redirect_to @recipe, notice: "Dodano nowy przepis"
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
            redirect_to @recipe
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @recipe.destroy
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Przepis został usunięty"
    end



    private

    def recipe_params
        params.require(:recipe).permit(:tittle, :description, :image, :portion, :preparation_time, ingredients_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy], directions__attributes: [:id, :step, :_destroy], recipe_ingredients_attributes: [:id, :quantity, :_destroy])
    end

    def find_recipe
        @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    end



end
```

Recipe Model:

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :directions, inverse_of: :recipe
    has_many :recipe_ingredients
    has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients,
                                    reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? },
                                    allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :directions,
                                    reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['step'].blank? },
                                    allow_destroy: true


    validates :tittle, :description, :image, presence: true
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "400x400#" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

Direction model:

```
class Direction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe, inverse_of: :directions
end
```

Line from console about creating new Recipe object:

```
Started PATCH "/recipes/5" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-13 14:26:06 +0200
Processing by RecipesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"h4Htdlybl6hiej2msXb5jlNz0Yngz3Mw2Trju9822FgPatUASvQx+it7m+p3WSBX9k7vjLOhJU3vhgtEFlvzIw==", "recipe"=>{"tittle"=>"Tosty", "description"=>"Testowy przepis", "preparation_time"=>"10.0", "portion"=>"2", "ingredients_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Chleb tostowy", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"name"=>"Ser zółty", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"name"=>"Cebula", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"3"}}, "directions_attributes"=>{"1507897562367"=>{"step"=>"sdfsfd", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1507897565151"=>{"step"=>"sdfsdfs", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Recipe", "id"=>"5"}
  Recipe Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: directions_attributes
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Ingredient Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "ingredients".* FROM "ingredients" INNER JOIN "recipe_ingredients" ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" WHERE "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = ? AND "ingredients"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)  [["recipe_id", 5]]
   (0.5ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/recipes/5
Completed 302 Found in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
```

As you can see above in db query string, direction attributes goes without id and this is probably main reason. Altough ... I have no idea how to fix that.

Please help as I'm fighting with this issue for quite some time.

Comment: you require `image`, yet you don't pass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of `Unpermitted parameter: directions_attributes`.

`directions__attributes` remove extra `_` in strong params.

Inside

```
def recipe_params
        params.require(:recipe).permit(:tittle, :description, :image, :portion, :preparation_time, ingredients_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy], directions__attributes: [:id, :step, :_destroy], recipe_ingredients_attributes: [:id, :quantity, :_destroy])
    end
```

change to `directions_attributes`. It will works.